# Windows ListView control (or similar) that can have multiple columns of checkboxes?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, listview, checkbox

OK, so my Windows application involves a window that, among other things, has a list of objects in a pane. Each object has 8 boolean values that need to be determined — so I'd like a list of the objects, with eight columns of checkboxes after. I'm not using MFC, should that be relevant.

ListView *looks* the way I want it to, but apparently it doesn't accept checkboxes in SubItems (the `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` style only gives each row a checkbox on the left).

So what I need is some kind of alternative to ListView that **does** allow this. I've been looking, but nothing I've found seems to work.

I have seen reference to some `DataGridView` control, but I don't see that as an option in my Visual Studio 2010 "toolbox" — how does one access it, is it even available for non-MFC C++ projects? Most references to it seem to be for VB or C#.

Another thing I found is is this [custom ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx), but it, again, seems to be for C# and not C++. I'd certainly accept suggestions on how to use this resource in my code, if there's a simple way to interface with the C# dialogue (I'm completely unfamiliar with C#).

Anyway, any thoughts, suggestions, or tips anyone has, would be most appreciated!

EDIT: This should maybe go in a new question, but it doesn't really seem deserving an entire question on its own: MFC *seems* to have more support for this kind of thing (insofar as most of the custom controls I can find to download are for MFC). My project does not actually **require** being non-MFC, it just **is**, at the moment. How much work am I looking at to convert it?

Comment: DataGridView is .net so you will not see it for any Win32 project, whether that's plain Win32 or MFC. It's likely you'll need some kind of custom control, finding a grid control might be the easiest as there are many of those around since they tend to be more flexible than just a listview. What UI toolkit are you using, if any? What are you looking in the VS toolbox for if you're not using MFC?

Comment: In Visual Studio's "Resource View" I can make my window with a WYSIWYG editor; off on the right side there's a "Toolbox" that contains various controls I can drag and drop onto my window. This doesn't require MFC; I can just interact with it through the normal Windows message system. Anyway, does anyone know of a good grid control that's easy to use?

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the resource dialog editor. Thanks.

Comment: Just as an aside, speaking from personal experience that is not a very good user interface.

Comment: @Luke: Well, what would you suggest? I have 8 booleans per item that I need to expose to the user, in what may be a lengthy list of items. It won't be pretty to work with, sure, but I can't really think of a better way to design it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've taken the plunge and started using MFC; the [`CGridCtrl`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx) I downloaded seems to be working pretty well, though I still have a lot of work on it. I'm going to call this the answer, then, since there doesn't seem to be another forthcoming.